# Variables using in Expect/TCL in Bash Script (missing operand at _@_)

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

Hej all,

I want to use expect code in a bash script. For background information here I got my solution for the expect script: [Save terminal output to variable in expect/tcl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728767/save-terminal-output-to-variable-in-expect-tcl)

The script works fine when I use it stand alone. But I want to use it in a bash script for processing multiple files, I have problems with the variables inside the expect part.

I got these error:

```
set new error bounds? (0: no, 1: yes): missing operand at _@_
in expression "  _@_> 0.3 ||  > 0.3 "
(parsing expression "  > 0.3 ||  > 0.3 ")
...
```

Code:

```
#! /bin/bash
MLI_offs=$1 
MLI_snr=$2
MLI_diff_par=$3

/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn offset_fitm $MLI_offs $MLI_snr $MLI_diff_par MLI_coffs MLI_coffsets 7.0 6 1
set range 1.5
set azimuth 1.5

while {true} {
expect "enter minimum SNR threshold:"
send "7.0\r" 

expect "enter the range and azimuth error thresholds:" 
send "$range $azimuth\r"

expect -re {range: ([0-9.]+)   azimuth: ([0-9.]+)} {
    set range   $expect_out(1,string)
    set azimuth $expect_out(2,string)
}

expect "set new error bounds? (0: no, 1: yes):" { 
    if { $range > 0.3 || $azimuth > 0.3 } {
        send "1\r"
    } else {
        send "0\r" 
        break
    }
}
}
interact

EOF
```

Thanks,
Bjoern

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the variables are being substituted inside bash as well as Tcl/Expect. Since bash replaces unknown variables with the empty string, this leaves an entirely wrong script (which in turn complains because it can't figure out what's going on). It will have broken other things too (the use of `expect_out`) but it happens you've not hit it.

The simplest thing is to stop using bash as a wrapper as Tcl's quite adept at doing that sort of thing itself via the `argv` global. Thus:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect
set MLI_offs [lindex $argv 0]
set MLI_snr [lindex $argv 1]
set MLI_diff_par [lindex $argv 2]
# Alternatively, replace the preceding three lines with:
#    lassign $argv MLI_offs MLI_snr MLI_diff_par

spawn offset_fitm $MLI_offs $MLI_snr $MLI_diff_par MLI_coffs MLI_coffsets 7.0 6 1
set range 1.5
set azimuth 1.5

while {true} {
    expect "enter minimum SNR threshold:"
    send "7.0\r" 

    expect "enter the range and azimuth error thresholds:" 
    send "$range $azimuth\r"

    expect -re {range: ([0-9.]+)   azimuth: ([0-9.]+)} {
        set range   $expect_out(1,string)
        set azimuth $expect_out(2,string)
    }

    expect "set new error bounds? (0: no, 1: yes):" { 
        if { $range > 0.3 || $azimuth > 0.3 } {
            send "1\r"
        } else {
            send "0\r" 
            break
        }
    }
}
interact
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I'm not sure, but I think I need to run the expect code within the bash script, because thats only a part of the hole bash script. I got the variables (MLI_offs, MLI_snr, MLI_diff_par) from another process that runs before "offset_fitm" program. So if I run the expect-script stand alone I have to pass the variables from bash to expect.

Comment: Ok I think I solve it. I used `export var` in bash sript and `$env(var)` in expect script and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can escape the special '$' with a '\' for all expect(tcl) variables, to prevent Bash interpreting it. eg. `$range` should be writen as `\$range` in your Bash script.